# How to get the full path of the parent dir of a file in fish?

Tags: path, fish

In fish, say I have a file path from somewhere:

```
/aaa/bbb/ccc.txt
```

How can I get the full path of its parent dir? So I will get:

```
/aaa/bbb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the `dirname` command, and it is a Unix utility, not specific to fish.

For example, `cd (dirname /aaa/bbb/ccc.txt)`